# mod_rewrite: add character to back-reference-variable

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hyperlink

I have an url like this

```
img/(thumb)?/([size])?/file.jpg
```

and i want to rewrite it to this:

```
cache/file_thumb_[size].jpg
```

Because the 'size'- and the 'thumb'-parts are optinal, the url without these parts should have no underscore at the end.

Is there a way to rewrite this in **one** rule? I could solve the problem, if there is a way to add an underscore_character to the back-reference-variable.

```
RewriteRule ^img/((thumb)\/)?(([a-z]+)\/)?([-_0-9a-zA-Z]+).([a-z]{3})$ cache/$5_$2_$4.$6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it wouldn't be possible to include `_` only when the associated back-reference is available. The substitution string doesn't allow for what can be thought of as a conditional if else include operation.

However, you can achieve the same effect through chaining your rules as

```
RewriteRule ^img/(?:(thumb)/)?(?:([a-z]+)/)?(\w+)\.([a-z]{3})$ cache/$3_$1_$2.$4 [C]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)__(.*)$ $1_$2 [C]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)_\.(.*)$ $1.$2 [L]
```

Here's how the file name substitutions would happen

```
http://domain.com/img/thumb/small/file.jpg
 > Rule 1 > http://domain.com/cache/file_thumb_small.jpg

http://domain.com/img/thumb/file.jpg
 > Rule 1 > http://domain.com/cache/file_thumb_.jpg
  > Rule 3 > http://domain.com/cache/file_thumb.jpg

http://domain.com/img/small/file.jpg
 > Rule 1 > http://domain.com/cache/file__small.jpg
  > Rule 2 > http://domain.com/cache/file_small.jpg

http://domain.com/img/file.jpg
 > Rule 1 > http://domain.com/cache/file__.jpg
  > Rule 2 > http://domain.com/cache/file_.jpg
   > Rule 3 > http://domain.com/cache/file.jpg
```

Comment: Good hint, but unfortunately the code doesn't work. It looks good, but in my test the url "img/thumb/file.jpg" convert to "cache/file_thumb_.jpg/thumb/file.jpg".

Comment: Okay, the C-Flag cause the error. The first and the last rule should get a L-Flag, then it works! Thank you! I update your post.

Comment: @Olli, maybe your current Apache version doesn't support `[C]` flags but they are required in the sense that they chain the next rule to the current one. Without them the 2nd and 3rd rules would become independent and fire for non-image URL paths as well. This would cause problems in situations where you someday have `__` or `_.` in a file or directory name. The second and third rules would probably result in a `404` then. Just something you should be aware of.

Comment: Strange... yesterday, it don't work in 2 hours... now it works. Good advice! Thank you!